# Django custom user model authentication don't work

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I have an application 'homepage' with custom user model. I can register new user and see it in my DB.

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'homepage.User'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'auth_user'
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def authentication(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '') => one
    password = request.POST.get('password', '') => 1111 (not 1111 but hash)
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
```

user is always None.
I may retrieve it from db like this:

```
User = get_user_model()
user = User.objects.get(username='one')
print(user.username) => one
print(user.password) => 1111 (not 1111 but hash)
```

But I can't log in. How to make it work?

**EDIT:**
maybe something wrong in forms?

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
MyUser = get_user_model()

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
first_name = forms.CharField()
last_name = forms.CharField()
username = forms.CharField()
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, 
                            label="Password")          
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label="Confirm password")
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput)
birthday = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=YEARS))
phone_number = forms.CharField()
captcha = CaptchaField()

def save(self, commit = True):   
    user = MyUser.objects.create_user(self.cleaned_data['username'])
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.birthday = self.cleaned_data['birthday']
    user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
    user.set_password('password2')

    if commit:
        user.save() 

    return user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a problem was in forms.py:

```
user.set_password('password2')
```

I should save password like this:

```
user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
```

And it's ok now.

Answer (score 3):

If the value of `user.password` is 1111, then you've originally stored the value in plain test somehow; Django will always hash passwords for comparison, because the stored value should be hashed too.

Make sure you set the password originally with `user.set_password`, or create the User model with `User.objects.create_user`.

Comment: actually it prints something like: !shgKxtqOpu4lqUAPGFmTcDqho96auPUyKnvOmYkF. It prints 1111 if I save password like this: user.password = self.cleaned_data['password2'] (just for test)